# Append text to an attribute rather than replacing it?

Tags: jquery

I want to append some text to the title attribute of all elements of a certain class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In that context, `$(this)` is not the element of `$('.theclass')`.  Maybe you want to use [`each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each):

```
$('.theclass').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("title") + "Appended text.");
});
```

Answer (score 42):

I know this question is 7 years old. 
Just in case someone came across this question, here's the solution without using .each:

```
$('.theclass').attr("title", function() { return $(this).attr("title") + "Appended text." });
```

Answer (score 4):

JQuery has come a ways. There's a version of [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) that takes a function as the value argument:

```js
$('.theclass').attr('title', (i, value) => `${value || ""}appended text`);
```

`i` is the index of the attribute, `value` is the current value of the attribute... which might not be set, hence the `value || ""` expression, to avoid converting `undefined` into the string `'Undefined'` uglily.