# Change onclick of submit input in CSM page programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a CMS that I cannot directly edit, so I need to achieve the result via injected JS on the page.

My input submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$plcBody$BookingFormGrid$ctl03" value="NEXT" onclick="$('form').attr('action', 'RoomTypeSelection.aspx?bfid=126b48d6-e3b9-4e57-8be6-067da3425467&bfpid=37a70010-9228-4cd8-aeaf-23efd0ca4b84&arr=2019-03-13&amp;nts=4&a=1&c=0');" class="btn btn-primary bnow">
```

I have multiple of these (and of varying numbers) in the CMS page, and I need to add a parameter to the `onclick` url.

So:

```
onclick="$('form').attr('action', 'RoomTypeSelection.aspx?bfid=126b48d6-e3b9-4e57-8be6-067da3425467&bfpid=37a70010-9228-4cd8-aeaf-23efd0ca4b84&arr=2019-03-13&nts=4&a=1&c=0'
```

Becomes (with param `&pc=SAVENOW`):

```
onclick="$('form').attr('action', 'RoomTypeSelection.aspx?bfid=126b48d6-e3b9-4e57-8be6-067da3425467&bfpid=37a70010-9228-4cd8-aeaf-23efd0ca4b84&arr=2019-03-13&nts=4&a=1&c=0&pc=SAVENOW'
```

How can I change the `onclick` action content?

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/644905/1141944. It would be `$('form').attr('action', $('form').attr('action') + '&pc=SAVENOW');`

Comment: You either replace the event handler or add a new one. By the time you want to do this, the html is processed, the event handler from the attribute is precompiled. That is a problem for you as you can't simply edit its text. I suggest an other approach: as this event handler changes the action of a form, why not doing this on the form's side? I mean you can add an `onsubmit` handler and change the action property in it. You also gain a much maintainable code as your later additions will be clearly separated.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a sample code for reference:

```
<form onsubmit="changeValue(this)">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
   function changeValue(theForm) {
      theForm.action = 'RoomTypeSelection.aspx?bfid=126b48d6-e3b9-4e57-8be6-067da3425467&bfpid=37a70010-9228-4cd8-aeaf-23efd0ca4b84&arr=2019-03-13&nts=4&a=1&c=0';
return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you can't change the emitted html code, this is why you want to achieve your goal from JS. I meant something like this in my comment:

```
<script>
$(() => {
  $('form').on('submit', () => { $(this).attr('action') += '&pc=SAVENOW' })
})
</script>
```

However, your logic might become more complicated if you have to differentiate between forms, by not simply adding this parameter to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following @tshimkus suggestion. This does the trick. Thanks all.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr("onclick", function() { 
    var origOnclick = $(this).attr("onclick");
    var promoCode = "&pc=SAVENOW";

    if (origOnclick) {
        var position = origOnclick.indexOf('&arr');
        var output = [origOnclick.slice(0, position), promoCode, origOnclick.slice(position)].join('');
        return output; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Beware: the order of `onclick` handler execution is not defined, might differ from browser to browser. And now you have two on each. Think of what happens if your code is executed after the original code: your modification is totally lost. This is why I suggested handling it at the form, before you actually submit it, which is clearly fired after the original `onclick`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads up. I am running the changes to the link on dom ready, before the user can click a button. It seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox so far. Thanks